# Adapt an image to device's resolution

Tags: html, css

It shows fine on my laptop:

[image]

but not on mobile:

[image]

my question is, how can I make it so this is the background on mobile (ie it just centers the picture)

[image]

my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("../images/public/card.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.main {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/card.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <br>
    <h1>Request an icon</h1>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the image: https://unsplash.com/photos/_wrWomwTLRg

*(i know i can add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`)*

Comment: Try using the `background-position` property

Comment: Do you want something like the last image? What do you mean it just centers the image? Do you want another thing?

Comment: Ali Sheikhpur, I want the picture on PCs to be how it is in the first pic, but on mobiles like the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you tried simply doing it like this :

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your goal and what do you mean by "(i know i can add background-repeat: no-repeat;)" by this. whatever maybe this could help you.

```
background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593539651148-13fb61a49325?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80") no-repeat center
    center/cover;
```

this is `background` shorthand property